Does a thermistor's dissipation constant also apply to cooling when current stops? How is it connected to the thermal time constant?
If a thermistor has a dissipation constant of, for example, 0.5 mW/°C, then it is expected that dissipating 5 mW in the thermistor will raise the temperature 10°C above ambient. At that point the thermistor therefore is dissipating 5 mW into the environment.
If the current is suddenly removed and the thermistor is allowed to cool, can I expect the thermistor to cool at a rate of 0.5 mW/°C, where the °C part is the temperature difference between the thermistor and the environment and is continuously reducing as it cools, until it reaches ambient temperature?
If not, why not, and does the dissipation constant tell me anything about how it will cool?
Thanks.
